# How to choose max amount of rows in unknown period . Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
create table order(
id serial PK,
status varchar(255),
finish_time date
)
```

I want to choose the max number of orders with status = 'finished' in the period between 3 days

For example, let's say I have such content

```
select * from orders;

id | status | finish_time

1     'finish'  2018-09-10

1     'finish'  2018-09-11

1     'finish'  2018-09-12

1     'finish'  2018-09-12
```

from `September 10 to 12` (3 days) amount will be 4.

from `September 11 to 13` (3 days) amount will be 3

So the answer should be 4

What is my way to write such query in Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ideally want is window functions where `range between` works with dates.  Alas, Postgres does not (yet) support that.

Here is another approach:

```
select o.*, o2.cnt
from orders o cross join lateral
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from orders o2
      where o2.status = 'finish' and
            o2.finish_time >= o.finish_time - interval '3 day' and
            o2.finish_time <= o.finish_time
     ) o2
order by cnt desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a where clause with the date being greater than with a subquery to get the max day minus 3 days (Query 1).

Or, if you want a specific date with the 3 previous days, a where clause with the date being greater than against a subquery with that date - 3 days and lesser or equal to that date (Check query 2)

In example :

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id INTEGER,
  status VARCHAR(8),
  finish_time DATE
);

INSERT INTO orders
  (id, status, finish_time)
VALUES
  ('1', 'finish', '2018-09-07'),
  ('2', 'finish', '2018-09-08'),
  ('3', 'finish', '2018-09-09'),
  ('4', 'finish', '2018-09-10'),
  ('5', 'pending', '2018-09-10'),
  ('6', 'finish', '2018-09-11'),
  ('7', 'finish', '2018-09-12'),
  ('8', 'finish', '2018-09-12'),
  ('9', 'pending', '2018-09-13');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM orders o
WHERE o.status = 'finish'
AND o.finish_time > (SELECT MAX(ord.finish_time) - INTERVAL '3 DAY' FROM orders ord WHERE ord.status = 'finish');
```

**Result**

```
| id  | status | finish_time              |
| --- | ------ | ------------------------ |
| 4   | finish | 2018-09-10T00:00:00.000Z |
| 6   | finish | 2018-09-11T00:00:00.000Z |
| 7   | finish | 2018-09-12T00:00:00.000Z |
| 8   | finish | 2018-09-12T00:00:00.000Z |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM orders o
WHERE o.status = 'finish'
AND o.finish_time > (SELECT DATE('2018-09-11') - INTERVAL '3 DAY')
AND o.finish_time <= (SELECT DATE('2018-09-11'));
```

**Result**

```
| id  | status | finish_time              |
| --- | ------ | ------------------------ |
| 3   | finish | 2018-09-09T00:00:00.000Z |
| 4   | finish | 2018-09-10T00:00:00.000Z |
| 6   | finish | 2018-09-11T00:00:00.000Z |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nkLCZpc2HAeHaavj413cBi/3)

Comment: Sorry , but it didn't work , see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mAD6oHSPyGFHtYDdSpNcoM/0

In this example I need to choose days between 8 to 10 , but query choosed 9 to 12(12 to 9 is not 3 days , it 4 starting from 9-th)

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak I noticed that and fixed the fiddle